# How to join the content of an attribute in multiple rows with semicolon and delete doubles (QGIS)?

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, attribute-joins

I have a shapefile with a large number of buildings (polygons) and want to add an the parcel number from a different shapefile in QGIS. In most cases this works well using join by position.

However some buildings are located on two or more parcels and I would like to have both parcel numbers written in the attribute, preferably separated by a semicolon.

E.g.: I have a building with "ID" 01115 located on "GNR" 2823 and 2824. I now have two instances of "ID" 01115 in the attribute table, one for each parcel number. I want to have "ID" (01115) - "GNR" (2823; 2824). Is there an easy way to join the content of multiple rows in one and delete the doubles?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I found the answer. I can run *Concatenate(„GNR“,group_by:=“ID“,concatenator:=’; ‘)* in the field calculator and then do a *'Dissolve'* on the layer to get rid of the duplicates.